# Mars crater nomenclature

Tags: mars, naming, crater, nomenclature

The [Wikipedia page for planetary nomenclature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_nomenclature#Mars) states that small craters don't follow the same rule as large craters as far . What is the cutoff between small and large craters (as far as naming is concerned), if there is one at all? Is there a crater diameter under which craters are named for Earth towns and over which craters are named for scientists and writers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approximately 50km, according to the IAU [documentation on namimg planetary features](https://planetarynames.wr.usgs.gov/Page/Categories)

In practice, there is some overlap, with some smaller craters having names of scientists (often these are craters that were named in 1973) and some larger ones having place names, such as [Bamburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamberg_(crater))